# ID Gets changed because out of range value of datatype Big Int

Tags: mysql, bigint

I am getting this error in mySQL database.

I have a table where I have take ID column & its data type set BIGINT & values to 100.

Now I am trying to pass this ID (110585777261232376048) under but it gets changed to this (9223372036854775807).

I can't change length of my ID since its auto-generated dynamic value.

How do I change my column properties to make it work correctly?

Comment: Why not use a string data type instead?

Answer (score 0):

`BIGINT` unsigned can take a range of 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615. Try setting the column as `UNSIGNED BIGINT` .. It cannot accept a value beyond this. You need to convert the datatype to `DOUBLE` if the range exceeds this limit

Comment: That's still out by a factor of 10.

Comment: That sounds like a bad idea to me - although I see that floats are successfully used as PRIMARY KEYs, so maybe it's OK. Seems strange though.